# QProcess Reads each letter in string as separate

Tags: qt, pyqt, mkdir, qprocess, pyqt5

I'm trying to use a `QProcess` to run a `mkdir` command (I'm using linux). The process would create a folder on the user's Desktop called 'output'. The code looks like this:

```
def mkOutput():
    # get the user's environmental variables
    env = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
    proc = QtCore.QProcess()
    proc.setProcessEnvironment(env)

    # find the HOME variable, append it to args
    HOME = env.value('HOME', defaultValue='./')
    args = "/Desktop/output/"

    args = HOME+args

    proc.setStandardOutputFile('out.txt')
    proc.setStandardErrorFile('err.txt')
    proc.start("mkdir", args)
    proc.waitForFinished()
```

out.txt is empty while err.txt reads:

```
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘o’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘t’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘p’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘u’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘t’: File exists
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/’: File exists
```

For some reason it's trying to run `mkdir` on each letter in the argument rather than using the whole string itself.
I've tried to use str() to on the `args` variable but nothing seems to work. Every time it just creates multiple folders in the directory I run the program from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [`proc.start("mkdir", args)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qprocess.html#start), `args` should be a list or tuple. Because you are passing a string, PyQt is converting it into a list, making Qt receive a list of each of the characters of the string. To fix the problem, change `args = "/Desktop/output/"` to `args = ("/Desktop/output/",)`

BTW, Python has an [function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) for `mkdir()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the mkdir() instead but I had some other calls where the same thing was happening as well so that's good to know